# (Again) accessing long paths in Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows

I have read all the previous answers on StackExchange and on Google, but they don't seem to solve my problem.

[Long paths in Python on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557760/long-paths-in-python-on-windows)

[Python long filename support broken in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365797/python-long-filename-support-broken-in-windows)

[Long paths for python on windows - os.stat() fails for relative paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49054305/long-paths-for-python-on-windows-os-stat-fails-for-relative-paths)

[Windows path too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443197/windows-path-too-long)

I am adding '\\?\' in front of my filename, but it does not help. 
Here is my MWE:

```
test_path = '\\\\?\\d:\\' + ''.join(['a']*260)
print(test_path)
print(len(test_path))
with open(test_path, 'w'):
    pass
```

Just trying to save a long file on `d:` fails with

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-1ec52b105f8b> in <module>
      3 print(test_path)
      4 print(len(test_path))
----> 5 with open(test_path, 'w'):
      6     pass

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\\\\?\\d:\\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
```

Shorter filenames go through just fine. I am using `Python 3.7`.
What am I doing wrong?

Without '\\?\' the command fails with `FileNotFoundError`, as expected.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should use raw strings for Windows file paths, this way you don't need to escape the backslashes. `test_path = r'\\?\d:\'`

Comment: @Tomalak I don't know about whether I "should" (the approaches are equivalent), but thanks, I am actually doing that. Just simplified things for the MWE.

Comment: Of course it's your call. :)

Comment: @Tomalak, `r'\\?\d:\'` is invalid syntax. For whatever reason, a raw string in Python allows backslash to escape an embedded quote, but with the backslash retained (e.g. `r"a\"b"` is `'a\\"b'`). Thus a raw string cannot end with an odd number of backslashes, since the odd one out escapes the closing quote.  Doubling the final backslash won't work either (e.g. `r'\\?\D:\\'`). It's valid Python syntax, but an extended path is verbatim and doesn't allow repeated backslashes. You'd have to absurdly use `r'\\?\D:\\'[:-1]` -- instead of just `'\\\\?\\D:\\'`.

Comment: `'a' * 260` is too long for a component name. The maximum *component name* length in Windows filesystems is 255 characters or less. It's 255 for NTFS, ReFS, FAT32, and exFAT. The maximum *path name* length, where a path contains a device name and one or more component names, is 32,767 characters, but a bit less in practice since DOS device names expand to longer native device names (e.g. "C:" -> "\Device\HarddiskVolume2").

Comment: @ErykSun Oh yeah, you're right. Stumbled over this oddity before, didn't think about it when I wrote the comment.